# linux kernel source tree in c include directive -- how it works

Tags: c, linux, include, kernel, directive

I am trying to check how include directive in c search linux source tree for including kernel header files. For example in my /usr/src/linux-header-5.7.0-kali-common folder which contains subdirectory  include/linux I think this is the directory where avaiable kernel header files like socket.h and others are present and they do exists there. so if in c I try to include /usr/src/linux-header-5.7.0-kali-common/include/linux/socket.h header file like

```
#include <linux/socket.h>
```

then it works ok. I checked. but when I try to specify some header file in subdirectory of /usr/src/linux-header-5.7.0-kali-common/include/linux/ like file
/usr/src/linux-header-5.7.0-kali-common/include/linux/amba/bus.h which does exists

```
  #include <linux/amba/bus.h> (NOT working)
```

and tried to compiled it but gcc gave me error like no such file as <linux/amba/bus.h> exists

I like to know that does gcc not searches any place other place than current directory in linux source tree (may be this is a limitation implemented in some makefile which I dont know of or kernel header files are only self contained folder means no sub directories which in that case I may be wrong from the start because /usr/src/linux-header-5.7.0-kali-common/include/linux/ contains many subdirectories

Question
how can I achieve to include header files that are like #include <linux/netfilter/nfnetlink.h> which does exists in /usr/src/linux-header-5.7.0-kali-common/include/linux/netfilter/ folder
I tried to include it by specifying #include <linux/netfilter/nfnetlink.h> but does not work

Question
if someone try to explain when we include like this
#include <linux/socket.h> (WORKING)

which directory or directories may be searched

Comment: Probably you have `-I` followed by directory(ies) in some make file indeed. This is why IDEs are nice and command line crap isn't very nice.

Comment: Just for sure: Do you build a **kernel** module or an **user-space** application? The latter doesn't have `/usr/src/linux-header-5.7.0-kali-common/include/` directory to be included automatically.

Comment: If you are building a user-space application, then `#include <linux/socket.h>` is probably including "/usr/include/linux/socket.h".